# scipy overwriting warning filters?

Tags: python, scipy

It seems as though some scipy modules are messing with my warning filters. Consider the following code. My understanding is that it should only throw **one** warning because of the "once" filter I supplied to my custom Warning class. However, the warning after the scipy import gets shown as well.
This is with python 3.7 and scipy 1.6.3.

```
import warnings
class W(DeprecationWarning): pass
warnings.simplefilter("once", W)

warnings.warn('warning!', W)
warnings.warn('warning!', W)

from scipy import interpolate

warnings.warn('warning!', W)
```

This only seems to happen when I import certain scipy modules. A generic "import scipy" doesn't do this.

I've narrowed it down to the filters set in `scipy.special.sf_error.py` and `scipy.sparse.__init__.py`. I don't see how that code would cause the problem, but it does. When I comment those filtersout, my code works as expected.

Am I misunderstanding something? Is there a work-around that that doesn't involved overwriting `warnings.filterwarnings`/`warnings.simplefilters`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This an open Python bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue29672.

Note, in particular, the last part of the [comment by Tom Aldcroft](https://bugs.python.org/issue29672#msg390103):

> Even a documentation update would be useful. This could explain not only `catch_warnings()`, but in general the unexpected feature that if any package anywhere in the stack sets a warning filter, then that globally resets whether a warning has been seen before (via the call to `_filters_mutated()`).

The code in [`scipy/special/sf_error.py`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/sf_error.py) sets a warning filter, and that causes a global reset of which warnings have been seen before. (If you add another call of `warnings.warn('warning!', W)` to the end of your sample code, you should see that it does not raise a warning.)

Comment: Wow, much thanks!!! For the life of me I could not figure this out. I've implemented a work-around in my package by importing the offending package modules first thing in my __init__, then applying my own filters.